# Removing decimal place from int or string in Python

Tags: python, decimal

I have a text file with a string like 0.0.1 and I want to remove the decimals to make it 001 or just 1. So for example a 1.0.1 would become a 101.

I thought about using the round() but it would turn 0.0.1 into 0 and that's not what I want.

Comment: please post your text file

Comment: the text file would like 
# 0.0.1

Comment: You can use the built in `replace()` function to replace all of the periods with an empty string. The implementation is `new = old.replace('.','')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just remove the '.' between the digits:

```
s = '0.0.1'
s = s.replace('.', '')
```

after that you can make it an int:

```
int(s)
```

By making it an integer, you will also remove any leading zeros. If you need a string afterwards just convert it back to string:

```
s = str(int(s))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `join` and a comprehension:

```
>>> s = '0.0.1'
>>> ''.join(c for c in s if c != '.')
'001'
```

If you want to strip the leading 0s:

```
>>> str(int(''.join(c for c in s if c != '.')))
'1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace()`

Try something like this code block:

```
new_file = open('newfile.txt','w')

line_file = open('myfile.txt','r').readlines()

for line_in in line_file:
    line_out = line_in.replace('.','')
    new_file.write(line_out)
```

That should read your file, remove all the periods, and write the result to a new file.

If it doesn't work for your specific case, comment on this answer and I'll update the codeblock to do what you need.

p.s. As per the comment below, you could make this happen in one line with:

```
open('newfile.txt','w').write(open('myfile.txt','r').read().replace('.',''))
```

So use that if you want to.

Comment: There's certainly a way to do it that way, though I prefer `readlines()` as it makes the file easier to iterate through as a list of strings. As part of the list making process, it does strip the newline character. it could be done as `new_file.write(open('myfile.txt'.'r').read().replace(',',''))` but that isn't readable for someone new to the concept.

Comment: no, readlines does not strinp newlines, you will be adding blank lines adding another, why is calling readlines easier than iterating over a file object. `with open("myfile.txt") as f:for line in f:...`, using read or readlines reads the whole file into memory which is not always possible

Comment: Iterating isn't easier to do, it's simply easier for someone to understand. I'm trying to show the OP how it works, rather than simply provide code. I have appended a way to do the whole thing the way I think is the best way. But it's one highly structured line with no iteration.

Comment: using `with` to open  and iterating over the file object would be the pythonic way to do it, you are still adding blanks lines in between adding another newline  in your first example, readlines does not strip.